# How to compare an element in a list to the others (here, in C#)?

Tags: c#, list, foreach, skip

How is it possible (in my case in C#) to compare an element in a list to all other elements in the list, but (of course) NOT to itself - and to do this for all elements?

Example:

```
List <sometype>  A = new List<sometype> ();


Foreach (sometype e_1 in A)
{
    Foreach (sometype e_2 in A)
    {
       // compare e_2 to the other elements in A except e_1
    }
}
```

That means that I must exclude 'e_1' in the 2nd loop, but how can I do this?
Whe I use

```
 Foreach (sometype e_2 in A.Skip() )
```

in the 2nd loop I hav to know the index of 'e_1'. Wehre I can find this easyly?
Or is there another way?

Thx a lot :-)

Comment: Comparing it to all other elements for the purposes of...? Sorting? Finding a particular value? Counting distinct equivalence groups?

Comment: If you need the index, then use a `for` loop rather than `foreach`.

Comment: Define "itself" first. Something with the same reference something with the same identification property something with the same content or something else. If you have that definition check for that in the loop.

Comment: If you use a standard `for` loop (`for (i = 0 ; i < something ; i++)`) you will have the index, and also your inner loop only needs to scan the items _after_ the index in the first loop (consider three items A, B, C: the combos you need are A/B, A/C and B/C - that covers them all).

Comment: naively: `A.Where(e => e != e_1)` ; or maybe use index instead of foreach. first loop use i = (1, n), and second loop is j = (i+1, n), compare A[i] and A[j]. not sure about latter one though, quick thought, might not be correct

Comment: A.Where(e => e != e_1) ;  Wow, if this mechanism will work, then my problem is solved. An easy and smart way. Thank you!

Comment: If you want all items without duplicates -> `A.Distinct()`, if you want only duplicates,`A.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(y => y.Key)`.

Comment: Note that Skip() doesn't do what you think it does; what you tried there with `Foreach (sometype e_2 in A.Skip() )` would be more like `foreach(sometype e_2 in A.Except(new[]{e_1}))`. Skip ignores N elements from the start of a sequence, it does not ignore the Nth element of a sequence

Comment: *"but (of course) NOT to itself"* -- There is nothing wrong with comparing something with itself, which makes the parenthesized "of course" out of place to say the least.

Comment: A.Distinct() looks also very good.  @comment4 : The goal is a hpgl optimizer: I have a list of line coordinates and I want to connect lines if start or and coordinates are same to that from another line in the list. To achieve that, I run throuh my list and compare each line (=coordinates)  to the others. When I find 2 fitting ones, I glue them and remove them from the list in a new one.

Answer (score 3):

As an easy way out, you can turn `foreach` into `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; ++i) {
  var e_1 = A[i];

  for (int j = 0; j < A.Count; ++j) {
    // We don't compare item with itself
    if (i == j)
      continue;

    var e_2 = A[j];

    // compare e_2 to the other elements in A except e_1
  }
}
```

If you *insist* on `foreach` (say, you have `A` being `LinkedList<T>`, not `List<T>`) and you don't want to cache the enumeration in the collection (which means, that you are ready to enumerate several times) you can do the same trick with a little help of *Linq:*

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (var (e_1, i) in A.Select((item, index) => (item, index))) 
  foreach (var (e_2, j) in A.Select((item, index) => (item, index)))
    if (i != j) {
      // compare e_2 to the other elements in A except e_1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Stupid solution: use **for** by i and **for** by j where **i != j**

If you need just unique items, use HashSet, hashSet.Add will return false if it already have the item.

Comment: I know, but I think thats it's not smart and safe and i would say kind of bad code... :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to persist with `foreach` loops you could just skip in the inner loop if you detect that the two objects you want to compare live at the same memory location:

```
        foreach (var e_1 in A)
        {
            foreach (var e_2 in A)
            {
                if(Object.ReferenceEquals(e_1, e_2)) continue; //if the objects have the same memory address, skip
                   
                // compare e_2 to the other elements in A except e_1
                Console.WriteLine($"{e_1} compared to {e_2}");
            }
        }
```

Using [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-8.0) will not perform any unnecessarily longer checks that `==` might perform; it just queries whether the two arguments refer to the same object in memory. See it in action here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaQBKH

This is subtly different to `==`, which may perform a more involved comparison, and declare two objects to be equal when they're actually different. You can see this in action in the following example, where the list is a bunch of ValueTuple objects `("a",1), ("a",1), ("b",1)` - there are two different `("a",1)` with the same content:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0XNSQM

If you used ReferenceEquals then you *would* see the code reach the point where it prints the comparison message for the case where the first `("a",1)` is compared to the second `("a",1)`, but because `==` performs the more in-depth comparison of looking at the data content of each member in a ValueTuple, `==` will pronounce the two `("a",1)` to be equivalent, even though the second one is not the "itself" of the first one etc

Think carefully about what "itself" means to you, and choose your `Equals`/`ReferenceEquals`/`==` appropriately